# Exponential recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, exponential-function, economics

I am currently struggling to find a closed form solution for a recurrence relation and don't know where to start. I have worked with linear homogenous first and second-order relations before but this is unlike anything I have seen. Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

$$k_{t+1}=A(1-\alpha)(1-\beta)g^tk_t^\beta$$

where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are strictly between $0$ and $1$, $t>0$, $k_1>0$, $g$ is a growth rate and $A$ is a positive real constant.

Comment: UI'm just spitballing here, but you might let $u+t = \log k_t$; taking logs would get you a recurrence $$u_{t+1} = \log A + \log (1-\alpha) + \log (1-\beta) + t \log g + \beta u_t,$$ which has the form $$u_{t+1} = C + Dt + E u_t,$$ which may be easier to approach with methods you already know.

Comment: Like 1. combine $A(1-\alpha)(1-\beta)$ to some $C$ 2. Take $\log$. : $\ln k(t+1)=\ln C+t\ln g+\beta \ln k(t)$ 3. Rearrange $\ln C+t\ln g$ between $k(t+1)$ and $k(t)$ by letting $y(t)=\ln(k(t))+at+b$ where $y(t+1)=\beta y(t)\Leftrightarrow \ln k(t+1)=\ln C+t\ln g+\beta \ln k(t)$. Then $y(t)=\beta^ty(0)$, viola.